# Passing arguments stored as a string to a function using shinymanager

Tags: r, shiny

I know that this question has been asked repeatedly, but the usual solutions using `eval(parse(text = x))` and `get(x)` have not been working for me.

I would like to store function arguments as either a string or in a list and pass them into a function:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)
library(shinythemes)

## this works but is not what i want
ui <- secure_app(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
  tags_bottom = tags$h5("If you are having issues logging in - chill and order a pizza."),
  fluidPage()
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Something like this is what I want, which current does not work:

```
arguments <- "theme = shinytheme('flatly'),
tags_bottom = tags$h5('If you are having issues logging in - chill and order a pizza.')"

ui <- secure_app(
  arguments,
  fluidPage()
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(shinymanager)
library(shinythemes)

#start a new line between arguments
arguments <- "theme = shinytheme('flatly'),
tags_bottom = tags$h5('If you are having issues logging in - chill and order a pizza.'),
ui = fluidPage()"

cleaning <- str_split(arguments, ',\n') %>%
              transpose() %>%
              flatten() %>%
              map(~ str_split(.x, ' = ')) %>% #separate the argument name from the code to evaluate
              set_names(map(., ~.x[[1]][[1]])) 
    
listing <- cleaning %>%
             map_df(~ .x[[1]][[2]]) %>% # a dataframe where each cell is an expression
             map(~eval(parse(text = .x[[1]]))) 




ui <- exec(secure_app, !!!listing) #pass the arguments as a list
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```